# Download multiple views in as single PDF file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a MVC3, Razor engine application having 8 different views(.cshtml).I have these pages for users to enter personal details and other things. I can download each page at time(Used Rotativa to acheive it).But i need to download all these 8 views as a single PDF file.Each views have  different models but only one controller.Please Help

Answer (score 0):

> Just make another Action inside the same 
>   controller that you have already created, i Just name it as "GetAllViewtoPDF".
>   Isnside this action write your logic to get
>   all views data and process to pdf, i am supposing that
>   all view data is containing same person data at a time.

Now put a button in anyofview/allview and on click of that button call the
"GetAllViewtoPDF" action.